# How to get the array value using loop and pass the value to the function?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Sorry for the title of my question. It is hard for me to explain this so to make my problem short.
I just need to pass the values from my table to my function. I put the information from my table in an array and I need to use that array because it will serve it as the parameter for my function.

Here's the sample code.

```
$dragonpay = "SELECT * FROM dragon_pay";
$resultDragonPay = $this->db->query($dragonpay);

foreach($resultDragonPay->result_array() as $dragonpay_value){

    $dragon[] = array(
        'transaction_id' => $dragonpay_value['transaction_id'],
            'SC_REF' => $dragonpay_value['SC_REF']
    );

}
```

This is the sample output using print_r($dragon)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [transaction_id] => 122451
            [SC_REF] => LL877KG4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [transaction_id] => 122563
            [SC_REF] => ERQKX2A0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [transaction_id] => 122696
            [SC_REF] => AM383D62
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [transaction_id] => 123549
            [SC_REF] => E88JNWB6
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [transaction_id] => 122407
            [SC_REF] => 734T3AK3
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [transaction_id] => 123352
            [SC_REF] => QFL45SM2
        )
```

Now my problem is the values from my array. Each of the index values should be use as a parameter.
Now I have this function. The use of this function is for data encryption.

```
   $info_data = @serialize($array_here);
   $encrypt_data = fn_encrypt_text($info_data);
```

Example scenario:

```
   $array_to_enrypt = array(
       'name' => 'myname',
       'gender' => 'mygender'
   )

   $info_data = @serialize($array_to_enrypt);
   $encrypt_data = fn_encrypt_text($info_data);
```

But I included all the values from my array. How can I get every value and use this as a single array? Do I need to include this in the loop? That's all guys I hope you understand what I mean. Thanks.

Comment: You want `myname` and `mygender` to be passed to `fn_encrypt_text()` how exactly ? Why not as 2 params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
function dragon_pay(){
    $data  = $this->db->get('dragon_pay')->result_array();
    if( is_array( $data ) && count( $data ) > 0 ){
        foreach( $data as $key => $each ){
            $dragon = array(
                            'transaction_id'    => $dragonpay_value['transaction_id'],
                            'SC_REF'            => $dragonpay_value['SC_REF']
                        );
            $info_data = @serialize($dragon);
            $encrypt_data = fn_encrypt_text($info_data);
            call_to_another_function( $encrypt_data ); #this is the function you want to call with the encrypted text?
        }
    }
    print_r( $data );
}
```